# C++ placement new, Invalid read and InvalidInvalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()

Tags: c++, valgrind, new-operator, free, realloc

I'm experimenting the usage of placement new to try to understand how it works.

Executing the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

#define SHOW(x) std::cout << #x ": " << x << '\n'

template<typename T>
static T *my_realloc(T *ptr, size_t count) {
    return (T *) realloc((void *) ptr, count * sizeof(T));
}

template<typename T>
static void my_free(T *ptr) {
    free((T *) ptr);
}

int main() {

    constexpr int count = 40;
    
    int cap = 0;
    int size = 0;
    std::string *strs = nullptr;
    
    auto tmp_str = std::string();
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        tmp_str = std::to_string(i);
        
        if(size == cap) {
            if(cap == 0)
                cap = 1;
            else
                cap *= 2;
            strs = my_realloc(strs, cap);
        }
        new (&strs[size++]) std::string(std::move(tmp_str));
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        SHOW(strs[i]);
    
    std::destroy_n(strs, size);
    my_free(strs);

    return 0;
}
```

I get the errors:

```
    Invalid read of size 1
    Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
```

Removing the line

```
    std::destroy_n(strs, size);
```

The error of invalid free is solved, but somehow all memory of the program is freed and no leaks are generated. But i can't find how the std::string destructor is called in the program.

Comment: `realloc` can fail, in which case the original memory remains allocated and you have to free it. But `strs = my_realloc(strs, cap);` will overwrite the original address with `nullptr` making it impossible to handle this case (which you don't even test for).

Comment: Note that `std::string` might have the small string optimization. Instead of allocating memory on the heap and tracking the address and capacity of the allocation a small string is stored directly in `std::string`. The `std::string` is a union of `small_string` and `heap_string` so to speak. If all your strings are small then you might not have any heap allocations for the strings and then and only then your code without `std::destroy_n` would have no leaks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store non-trivial types (such as `std::string`), then `realloc` simply cannot be used. You will find that standard library containers like e.g. `std::vector` will also not use it.

`realloc` may either extend the current allocation, without moving it in memory, or it might internally make a new allocation in separate memory and copy the contents of the old allocation to the new one. This step is performed as if by `std::memcpy`. The problem here is that `std::memcpy` will only work to actually create new objects implicitly in the new allocation and copy the values correctly if the type is [trivially-copyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable) and if it and all of its subobjects are [implicit-lifetime types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ImplicitLifetimeType). This definitively doesn't apply to `std::string` or any other type that manages some (memory) resource.

You are also forgetting to check the return value of `realloc`. If allocation failed, it may return a null pointer, which you will then use regardless, causing a null pointer dereference, as well as a memory leak of the old allocation.

Instead of using `realloc` you should make a new allocation for the new size, then placement-new copies of the objects already in the old allocation into the new one and then destroy the objects in the old allocation and free it.

If you want to guarantee that there won't be memory leaks when exceptions are thrown things become somewhat complicated. I suggest you look at the `std::vector` implementation of one of the standard library implementations if you want to figure out the details.

Comment: Or move the objects if they are movable. For std::string a move will be a lot faster as it avoids making a new allocation for the string data (for long strings).

Comment: I wish there would be a `try_realloc` that simply fails when it can't increase the allocated memory block instead of copying it. Because for those cases where the allocation can be extended in place a `realloc` would be worlds faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
strs = my_realloc(strs, cap);
```

`strs` is a pointer to a `std::string`, and this will result in the contents of the pointer to be `realloc()`ed.

This is undefined behavior. C++ objects cannot be `malloc`ed, `realloc`ed, or `free`ed. Using a wrapper function, or placement new, at some point along the way, does not change that.

Everything from this point on is undefined behavior, and the resulting consequences are of no importance.

Comment: I think your second paragraph is being too broad. The issue here is specifically with `realloc`. A simple `malloc`/`free` with the placement-new as shown would have been fine (and well-defined with the C++20 implicit object creation rules).